# Values of All of the Buttons Changing When Only Clicking On One of the Buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working on the counter buttons, but every time I click on one of the buttons, the values of all buttons automatically change. I'm new to reactjs so it would be great if someone could point me to the right direction. Thanks!

This is what my code looks like:

```
mport React from "react";
import {Card} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import "./Box.css"
//const soup = require("./soup.jpeg");
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


class MenuPage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            foodName : '',
            price : 0,
            amount : 0,
            counter: 0

        }
    }

    increment(){
        this.setState({
            counter: this.state.counter + 1
        });
    }

    decrement(){
        if(this.state.counter <= 0){
            this.setState({
                counter:0
            });
        }else {
            this.setState({
                counter: this.state.counter - 1
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        const cardInfo = [
            {image : "" , title: "Soup", price: "$6.0"},
            {image : "", title: "Pancakes", price:"$7.4"},
        ];
        const renderCard = (card,index) => {
            return(
                <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} key = {index} className="box">
                    <Card.Img variant="top" src = {card.image} />
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title>{card.title}</Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text>
                            {card.price}
                        </Card.Text>
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" id="minus" onClick={this.decrement.bind(this)}>-</button>
                        <input type="text" id="index" value={this.state.counter}/>
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" id="plus" onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>+</button>
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            )
        }
        return <div className= "grid">{cardInfo.map(renderCard)}</div>;

    }
}
export default MenuPage;
```

This is what my UI currently looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MenuPage keeps the `counter` state, and each separate card just shows the state of the menupage.

If you want each card to have its own state, you have to make the card a component. Then you give the Card Component a state with a counter.

The menupage can then show a ton of Card components. Then they will each have their own state.

Example Card Component with counter state

```
class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { clicks: 0 };
  }

  buttonClicked() {
    this.setState({clicks: this.state.clicks+1});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>{this.props.name}</h4>
        <div>Clicks: {this.state.clicks}</div>
        <button onClick={()=>this.buttonClicked()}>Add one</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Rendering multiple cards, each with their own counter state

```
class MenuPage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card name="Noodles"/>
        <Card name="Pancakes"/>
        <Card name="Soup"/>
      </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: If possible, could you give me an example? I've been searching online and I couldn't find related tutorials.

Comment: I added React code that shows cards that each have their own counter state. You can use props to give each card its own unique name.